# Add a user to the firewalls' user list in Silex

Tags: php, authentication, silex

I'm new to Silex and Symfony and decided to use Silex to build a (really) small app which uses an authentication. The auth process is working. I'm currently working on a little setup page which allows the user to define his username and password. The auth looks like this:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
  'admin' => array(
    'pattern' => '/private',
    'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/private/login_check'),
    'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/private/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
    'users' => array(
      $username => array('ROLE_ADMIN', $passwd)
    )
  )
);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
```

No other type of user is defined appart from admin. The setup is meant to be run once by an admin.

I've tried customizing the username and the password the following ways:
First thing (this is common to everything I tried)):

```
// Default password and username 
$username='admin';        $passwd='5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg==';`

The following didn't work (no magical update):

`$app->post('/setup', function(Request $request) use ($app, $username, $passwd) {
   $username = $request->get('username');
   $passwd= $request->get('passwd');
});
```

so I tried something like:

```
$app->post('/setup', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
   $username = $request->get('username');
   $passwd= $request->get('passwd');
   $app['security.firewalls']['admin']['users'] =  array($username => array('ROLE_ADMIN', $passwd));
  $app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
});
```

with and without registering a new SecurityServiceProvider, and redifining the "users" part of the array. Merging didn't help either.

I'm a bit out of idea here :S How can I perform that?

Comment: You have to register the security provider outside your controller code. When the application hit the controller code the authentication is already done so no point in setting the security provider there. Can you please elaborate a little bit what is your ultimate goal? Do you want to add 2 static users? Do you want a registration form? What's the purpose of the /setup URI, add new users? If so, you need a user repository (db, file, or other in memory provider which doesn't loose its content when the request is finished)

Comment: The pupose of the app is to use 2 folders: one public and the other private accessible via an auth. The purpose: people who uses a (properly configure) server to store files only have to unzip my project file on the server to have a simple list of files protected via an auth. To make a file available to public, a simple mv is enough. The goal of the /setup endpoint (which is intended to be run once) is to provide a graphical way for people to configure what folders they intend to use as private and public and what username and password they want to use. I want to avoid db configs.

Comment: You can store your users on a separate file and with the setup read / write to that file (you can use json, yaml, direct php in that file, and read / write from and to it). As you commented below you don't want to use a db, which is fine, but you need some way to store users and your current setup is **really** messy (you shouldn't allow the app to write to the index.php file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dynamic Way

You are not saving your User anywhere. I assume you define `$username` and `$passwd` before you define `$app['security.firewalls']`, otherwise that should already throw an error.

What you need is an **User Provider**. Right now you are not saving the new user(s), and you are trying to just re-define your two static variables - without checking the given values if I may add - and that is wrong in multiple ways :)

Either you dive in a little bit and check out how to [Define a Custom User Provider in Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider) and if you have special requirements to an User-Object also probably [how to create an User-Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#security-crete-user-entity), or you use some already written user provider for the Silex security service, like:

[Silex-SimpleUser](https://github.com/jasongrimes/silex-simpleuser) by Jason Grimes

---

### Static Way

If you don't want to dynamically add/edit/delete users or you just have a handful of users, you can always just add your static users to the users array:

```
'users' => array(
  'admin1' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'encodedAndSaltedPW1'),
  'admin2' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'encodedAndSaltedPW2'),
  'admin3' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'encodedAndSaltedPW3'),
)
```

In this case you would need to encode and salt the PWs like described in the docs:

> // find the encoder for a UserInterface instance
>
> `$encoder = $app['security.encoder_factory']->getEncoder($user);`
>
> // compute the encoded password for foo
>
> `$password = $encoder->encodePassword('foo', $user->getSalt());`

Also see the [docs for the SecurityServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html) for more information.

---

### Your Way: Single-User-Provider

After your comments I understand your needs better.

You could of course have an own ordinary "Single-User-Provider" - this could go something like this:

```
$app->post('/setup', function(Request $request) use ($app) {

   $username = $request->get('username');
   $passwd= $request->get('passwd');

   $file = 'config.json';
   $config = array($username => array('ROLE_ADMIN', $passwd));
   file_put_contents($file, json_encode($config));

   return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('login'));
});
```

*Be aware that a json-file, without proper permissions, could be read by anyone - so make sure to put the encoded/salted password in it, by no means the readable one.*

And then you would need to read the config.json into your Firewall-Configuration:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
  'admin' => array(
    'pattern' => '/private',
    'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/private/login_check'),
    'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/private/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
    'users' => json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'))
  )
);
```

Please notice, that this code is untested and should more likely give you an idea. I hope this helps.

Comment: I saw those solutions but wanted to avoid DB as I want the app to be fully functionnal once the project is unzip without doing too much configuration (like setting up a db). Plus, I don't want to do users management, I just want to have a single user of type admin (which I've got) whose username and password can be graphically set by the user who extracted my project using the /setup endpoint. At the moment, I only provide a /password/{pwd} endpoint, so the user can copy his encoded and salted password to paste it in the index.php (which works, but feels really messy)

Comment: @Mebius Thanks for your comment - I edited my answer and hope this moves you forward

Comment: I actually did switch toward something like this in YAML (choosen over JSON because the coin told me so) and this worked at 100% for me :-)

Comment: @Mebius Nice, I'm glad it worked out! I love it when a plan comes together :)